# My internal SuperDrive gets power, but won't show up in macOS

Tags: high-sierra, optical-drive, dvd

I have a 2010 white MacBook with 10.13.6 High Sierra installed, and my internal SuperDrive isn't detected. It gets power and spins up when I put a DVD in it, but the drive doesn't show up. The eject button doesn't work, it doesn't show up in system report, and `drutil` doesn't see a drive. I've tried looking everywhere and can't find a solution. Is there anything I can do to fix this drive?

I already reset the SMC and NVRAM more than once.

Comment: Possibly it's a loose cable. That MacBook is not difficult to open just to check.

Comment: I've tried that already. I wish that was it.

Comment: TBH, external USB CD/DVD reader/writers are so inexpensive it may be worth spending a little money to bypass the internal drive altogether.

Comment: I already have one, I'd just like to get the internal one working again.